# How to turn off sound for Google+ notifications?

Tags: notifications, google-plus

How do I turn off audio notifications for Google+ (mail and groups) on a Samsung Galaxy Note 3?

Comment: Just some notes: Hash Brown has answered it below, but notifications are handled by each individual app so if don't want to mute the device, but want to mute a particular app it will be in that app's settings. If you want an app to never send you ANY notifications (e.g. a game) you can go to Settings>Applications> whatever app> Untick Notifications. (Only works on Android 4.1+ IIRC)

Answer (score 2):

Start up Google+

Goto top left corner,  to the overflow button (3 dots).

Tap on settings

Tap on account settings for which account you want to change notification settings.

Tap on notification.

Change sound file to an empty sound file. (To do that start voice recorder app and record a second of silence,  then save and use).

This can be done on all devices with Google+.